# Standards for creating a RESTful Geocoding webservice

Tags: web-service, geocoding, standards

I am about to start defining a new API which will allow our clients to perform Geo Coding lookups. I would like to follow any standards there are out there. However looking at a few examples:

- [The Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
- [Yahoo! Maps Web Services - Geocoding API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html)

They seem to be setup using their own standards... I was wondering if there is a recognised standard out there.. and if you could direct me to a site that uses the standard that would be great. Off the top of my head I can think of

- [GeoRSS](http://www.georss.org/Main_Page)
- [Atom with open search and geo extensions](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Geo/1.0/Draft_1)

However I'm not sure if these are recognised as the official standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also consider ESRI's recently released (Sept 2010) [Geoservices REST Specification](http://www.esri.com/industries/landing-pages/geoservices/geoservices.html)

Comment: Just a quick comment.  If you implement the above, make sure you do it same as ArcGIS v10, not 9.x.   9.x spec did not have the WKID in the geolocation result, so you'd have no idea if the result is in Lat Lon or meters or what.  That was a big blunder in 9.x. They fixed in 10 by #1) allowing incoming request to specify WKID and #2) result having a WKID attached to it.

Answer (score 3):

These might be some good contact/reference points.

[Opensource routing](http://openrouteservice.org/),
 It looks as though they spun their own. Very cool with walking and biking routing as well as driving!

[Opensource geocoding reviewed](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2010/03/more-open-source-geocoders.html) - This from March 2010.